# while loop with user input

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop as a method in a data interpreter that takes a condition and while the condition is true executes the body of the statement then returns the value once the condition is no longer true. If it doesn't execute then it returns 0. The problem I am having is that I don't understand how to have the while loop execute the body of the statement. Here is what I have so far, I need a point in the right direction as to what I am missing here:

```
public class WhileStatement<b> extends Statement {

private final Expression condition; 
private final Statement body;   


/**
 * @param c the condition for the while loop
 * @param b the body of the loop
 */
public WhileStatement(Expression c, Statement b) {

this.body = b; 
this.condition = c; 



}

/**
 * Interpret this statement, returning the resulting value.
 * 
 * @param env the current environment
 * 
 * @return The integer value from the statement that is the loop
 *         body when it is last executed, or IntegerValue 0 if the
 *         loop never executes.
 */
@Override
public IntegerValue interpret(Environment env) {

    IntegerValue cond = condition.interpret(env);
    IntegerValue bod = body.interpret(env);



    while (cond.equals(true)) { 
        return bod; 

    } 

    return new IntegerValue(0); 
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "executing the body"? What is the `Statement` type? What is the `Expression` type? Are they from `java.beans` or something of your own? What is `IntegerValue`?

Comment: How do you evaluate condition..? What makes it true/false? And what is a statement? Is it of type Runnable? if not, what do you mean by "execute the statement" Please be more specific.

Comment: `cond.equals(true)` how could this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should really put more effort in describing your code!

Assuming at least **you** know what you are doing and I understood your problem:

```
IntegerValue cond = condition.interpret(env);
IntegerValue bod = body.interpret(env);

IntegerValue result = new IntegerValue(0);

while (cond.equals(true)) { 

    // execute whatever you wanted here in whatever way you do it
    result = bod; 

} 

return bod;
```